# AR terms in SUR models - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to estimate a SUR model of the form

```
y_{1,t} = \alpha_1 +\beta_1 x_{1,t} + \beta_2 x_{2,t} + \beta_3 y_{1,t-1} +\epsilon_{1,t}

y_{2,t} = \alpha_2 +\beta_4 x_{1,t} + \beta_5 x_{2,t} + \beta_6 y_{2,t-1} +\epsilon_{2,t}
```

Define `mY = [y_1 y_2]` and  `mX = [x_1 x_2]`.

For this purpose I am doing

```
iT = size(mY,1); iN = size(mY,2);
mXsur = kron(mX, eye(iN));
mXsurCell = mat2cell(mXsur, iN*ones(iT,1));
iR = size(mXsur,2);
Mdl = vgxset('n', iN, 'nAR',1, 'nX',iR,'Constant',true);
[SurOutput, SurSDerror, ~,SURcov] = vgxvarx(Mdl, mY, mXsurCell);
```

The issue is that the bit of code `nAR`, 1 seems to add 1 lag of both `y` variables to each equation and I only wish to add one per equation. Is there a quick way to do this?

(Of course I can include the lagged terms manually in the `mX` matrix, but my question is whether we can do this via `vgxset` in a quicker way. I think not based on my reading of the help file, but still want to double check). Thanks